# Function which is Lipschitz differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let us consider $\Phi(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ which is Lipchitz differentiable. I am wondering if the following expression is whether true or not:

$$\Phi(\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{y}_2)-\Phi(\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{y}_1)-\langle \partial_y \Phi(\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{y}_2), \mathbf{y}_2-\mathbf{y}_1 \rangle = L \lVert \mathbf{y}_2-\mathbf{y}_1 \rVert,$$

where $L$ is the Lipchitz constant. Please also let me know any helpful study material in this regard.

Comment: What do you mean by "Lipschitz differentiable"?

Comment: Also: You clearly can't expect equality. The question would make more sense with $\le$ in place of $=$.

Comment: I think you are right. I was trying to replicate a result from a paper. It seems that it was a minor typo there. Thanks.